# Individual animation delay for lists in angular2/4

Tags: javascript, angular, animation

I want to set individual animation deplay periods for same the state in my angular2 component so that one item displays after a certian seconds after the other.

I have the following blocks

```
    <div class="cloud-detials" *ngIf="screen">
         <div class="col" [@fadeInLeft]="slide"></div>
         <div class="col" [@fadeInLeft]="slide"></div>
         <div class="col" [@fadeInLeft]="slide"></div>
   </div>
```

that all have the same animation effect

```
 trigger('fadeInLeft', [
            state('inactive', style({ animationName: 'fadeInLeft'})),
            transition('* => active', animate(800, keyframes([
                    style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)'}),
                    style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'none'})
            ]))
            )
        ])
```

and I want each block to display after the previous one after a set period of seconds.

How do I achieve such an effect using the web animations api ?

Comment: There is a `stagger` helper for metadata coming. Also `query`, and it's the query list of elements that really makes this happen. You can look at the `animations-preview` branch in the code, or even check out a build.

Comment: thanks, will look into it. Was getting crazy trying to solve this issue

Comment: Demo against the new changes here, for those interested: http://slides.yearofmoo.com/ng4-animations-preview/demo/

Comment: Thanks, I checked it out and it's just what i needed. Is it stable enough for use ?

Comment: It may or may not make a 4.2 release AFAIK, if not then maybe the next one. Worth noting that most things in the animations API are marked as experimental still in every release of Angular to date.